# What tools exist for continuously delivery of NodeJS environments?

Tags: node.js, monitoring, continuous-deployment

I'm currently attempting to implement a continuous delivery pipeline for NodeJS, and want to have a tool that is capable of;

- deploying and managing packages of an application
- rolling back deployments
- monitoring the deployments for potential rollbacks
- has a REST API.
- is not a SaaS solution.

I have tried go.cd, but it didn't have monitoring capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

I think the product that may suit your needs is [Codeship](http://blog.codeship.com/nodejs-continuous-integration/). There is a very good presentation about using this tool to deploy a simple web application, showing its capabilities.

A you can desume from its [features](https://codeship.com/features) it can:

- Automate your development and deployment workflow
- Run your automated tests and get notified
- Speed up your tests with ParallelCI, that runs your test
- Configure powerful deployment pipelines that run after successful tests to deploy your application to multiple environments
- access debug builds via SSH
- the API and Webhook enable you to integrate Codeship with the tools you are currently using

Check this out.

Comment: Sadly I can't use a SaaS offering like Codeship, for security reasons. I will update my original post. Thanks for the response.